# merge statement query

Tags: sql, oracle, merge-statement

```
MERGE INTO TempEmployee TARGET
USING Consultant SOURCE
ON (TARGET.EmpId = SOURCE.EmpId)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET TARGET.FirstName = SOURCE.FirstName, TARGET.LastName = SOURCE.LastName
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT INTO TempEmployee(EmpId, FirstName, LastName)
  VALUES(SOURCE.EmpId, SOURCE.FirstName, SOURCE.LastName);
```

Error starting at line 1 in command

> Error at Command Line : 7 Column : 10
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword
> 00926. 00000 -  "missing VALUES keyword"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

Comment: The syntax is `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (...` you do not want `INTO TempEmployee` as that is already implied from the initial `MERGE INTO` clause on the first line.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Shortly: wrong syntax. Should be

```
MERGE INTO tempemployee target
     USING consultant source
        ON (target.empid = source.empid)
WHEN MATCHED
THEN
   UPDATE SET target.firstname = source.firstname, target.lastname = source.lastname
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN
   INSERT     (empid, firstname, lastname)
       VALUES (source.empid, source.firstname, source.lastname);
```

See [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/MERGE.html#GUID-5692CCB7-24D9-4C0E-81A7-A22436DC968F) documentation.